# Как лучше всего на сайте хранить список участников какой-то группы?

Tags: mysql, база-данных, оптимизация, backend

В базе данных есть таблица пользователей и таблица групп. Каждый пользователь может одновременно состоять в нескольких группах. Необходимо быстро уметь узнавать и в каких группах состоит конкретный пользователь, и всех участников конкретной группы. Как это лучше сделать?

Основные идеи 2:
1) поддерживать у пользователя список групп и у группы список участников в виде файлов в системе (сомнительная)
2) создать таблицу "участий", т.е. такой-то пользователь состоит в такой-то группе

Хотелось бы узнать поподробнее

Comment: С вариантом 2 не вижу каких-либо проблем

Comment: Классическая связь M:N. Вариант 2.